# Javascript Calculator on PopUp problem with display value

Tags: javascript, popup, calculator

I have an HTML calculator in a pop up. Everytime i open it the first time the calculations are correct. if i hide the pop up and open it again when i press 6 instead of 6 it shows 66. and if i close it again and open it if i press 5 it shows 555 and etc. Here is my code:

Snippet:

```js
var calculator = document.querySelector('#calculator3');
var keys = calculator.querySelector('#calculator-keys3');
var num="";
keys.addEventListener('click', e => {

  if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    var key = e.target;
    var action = key.dataset.action;
    var keyContent = key.textContent;

    if (!action) {

      num = num + keyContent;

      document.getElementById("displayPayment").innerHTML = "num";
    }

    if (action === 'backspace') {
      num = num.slice(0, -1);
      document.getElementById("displayPayment").innerHTML = "num";
    }

    if (action === 'decimal') {
      num = num + ".";
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="calculator" id="calculator3">
  <div class="calculator-keys" id="calculator-keys3">
    <button type="button" value="1">1</button>
    <button type="button" value="2">2</button>
    <button type="button" value="3">3</button>
    <button type="button" value="4">4</button>
    <button type="button" value="5">5</button>
    <button type="button" value="6">6</button>
    <button type="button" value="7">7</button>
    <button type="button" value="8">8</button>
    <button type="button" value="9">9</button>
    <button type="button" class="key--operator" data-action="add">+/-</button>
    <button type="button" value="0">0</button>
    <button type="button" data-action="decimal" value=",">,</button>
    <button type="button" class="equal-sign" data-action="backspace" value="del"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unbind the event listener first `removeEventListener()` or check if it's already bound before adding the event listener.

```
var calculator = document.querySelector('#calculator3');
var keys = calculator.querySelector('#calculator-keys3');
var num="";

var eventListener = function(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    var key = e.target;
    var action = key.dataset.action;
    var keyContent = key.textContent;

    if (!action) {

      num = num + keyContent;

      document.getElementById("displayPayment").innerHTML = "num";
    }

    if (action === 'backspace') {
      num = num.slice(0, -1);
      document.getElementById("displayPayment").innerHTML = "num";
    }

    if (action === 'decimal') {
      num = num + ".";
    }
  }
}

keys.removeEventListener('click', eventListener);

keys.addEventListener('click', eventListener);
```

If you don't remove the first event, then a second event will be bound to the elements the second time you run this script.

Comment: can you provide an example, because i cant seem to make it work, thanks

Comment: I've added the example you requested.

Comment: Ah yes, `removeEventListener` takes a 2nd argument which is the event listener function so  so you need to restructure your code a bit. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add another event when someone click on "closing the model button" and in this you have to clear all the previous values in html so next time someone open the model no previous value is present.

Comment: I clear the previous values, thats not the case. It doesnt show the previous values. It shows the value that i clicked as many times as i opened the pop up. For example if i opened it 3 times and i click 4 it will display 444